# JavaScript - Getting Value of Div Content - Content Getting Replaced by Wrong String

Tags: javascript, html, string, function

Link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/325wuae6/).

If the `textarea` is blank, the content should say "you have to tell me a joke!" with Javascript.

Instead, even when the `textarea` is blank, the content is still getting changed to "was your joke funny?"

Relavant code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row"><!--third row -->

  <div class="col-2 joker">
      <img src="/joker.png"/>
      <p id="jokerDialogue">Tell me a joke</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
      <table>

      <tr>
      <td>Joke:</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>
      <textarea id="jokeQuestion" type="string" min="1" max="24" size="24"> 
      </textarea>
      </td>
      </tr> 

      <tr>
      <td>
      <input id="submit-joke" type="button" value="submit" class="js-button" 
      onclick="joker()">
      </td>
      </tr>

      </table>
  </form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-8">             
  </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function joker() {

   let content = document.getElementById("jokeQuestion");
   if (content != "") {
      document.getElementById("jokerDialogue").innerHTML = "Was your joke funny?";
   }
   else if (content == "") {
      document.getElementById("jokerDialogue").innerHTML = "You must tell me a joke!";
   }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a variable `content` and say that it's whatever the user enters in the `textarea` with the id `jokeQuestion`.

But even when `content` is blank, the `<p>` with the id `"jokerDialogue"` is still getting changed to `"Was your joke funny?"`

I thought that `if (content != "")` meant "if the content is not blank" - so then why is the function returning "Was your joke funny?" even when it's blank?

Comment: `content` is an *element*, not a string. If you want to extract the value of the textarea, you must extract its `.value`

Comment: Alright so attaching `.value` after `content` via `if (content.value != "")` created the expected result. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `value` of `content`:

```
let content = document.getElementById("jokeQuestion").value;
```

Now your code will work as expected.